# Why doesnt the value of other textbox2 doesnt change onchange of textbox1? (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, html

I have two textboxes and I want the value of `textbox2` to be just like `textbox1` when the checkbox is checked.

The value of `textbox2` should be uptaded automaticaly if the checkbox is checked when you write something in `textbox1`

```js
function keep(){
 if(document.getElementById("cb").checked){
  document.getElementById("t2").value = document.getElementById("t1").value;
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" onchange = "keep()"/>
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" />
```

Comment: It's working fine seems no issue at all

Comment: I want the value of t2 to be equal to value of t1.. when the checkbox is checked..

Comment: If it would have been working .. I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. Alert box is just for showing that alert is working.. I want the value of t2 to be equal to value of t1.. when the checkbox is checked..

Comment: @Nevermore if checkbox is checked t2 having value as t1. Your code snippet working. If checkbox is not checked do you want t2 to be blank? is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or remove event based on your checkbox state:

```js
function keep() {
  if (document.getElementById("cb").checked) {
    updateVal();
    document.getElementById("t1").addEventListener('keyup', updateVal);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("t1").removeEventListener('keyup', updateVal);
  }
}

function updateVal() {
  document.getElementById("t2").value = document.getElementById("t1").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" onchange="keep()" />
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out This Code :

```
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" onkeypress="keep()" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb"   />
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" />
```